# How to kick off multiple copies of a VM in Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, vhd

I got my VHD in Hyper-V and it's running great. Since I got a great big server, I'd like to fire up a number of copies of this VHD.  How do I do that?  I didn't see anything obvious in the UI.

Answer (score 4):

You can't run multiple copies of the *same* VM, but you can clone it and start up multiple individual machines.

I'm going to assume this is straight Hyper-V without any SCVMM installed. So it's a two-step process.

1. Right-click on the powered-off VM and choose "Export". Run through the export wizard.
2. On the right-hand bar, click "Import VM".

   - Make sure you select the option "Duplicate the files" so that you can import it multiple times
   - Make sure you select the radio "Copy" (otherwise you end up with duplicate MAC addresses and whatnot)

Comment: you can run multiple copies of the same vhd but not the same vm, just doesn't do much good typically.